# Array to JSON failed on unexpect "="

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to make JSON to send it to webservice. Final json should looks like:

```
{
  "name": "Pravidlo",
  "partQualities": [
    "A",
    "O",
    "N"
  ],
  "residualValueMax": 100,
  "residualValueMin": 0,
  "selectionStrategy": "MIN_PRICE",
  "suppliers": [
    864,902,903,907,910,911,913,914,915,916,917,957
  ],
  "vehicleAgeMax": 100,
  "vehicleAgeMin": 0
}
```

What I did try:

```
    $data = array (
        "name" => "Pravidlo",           
        "partQualities" => array(
            'A', 'O', 'N'
        ),          
        "residualValueMax" = "100",
        "residualValueMin" = "0",
        "selectionStrategy" = "MIN_PRICE",
        "suppliers" = array(
            864,902,903,907,910,911,913,914,915,916,917,957
        ),   
        "vehicleAgeMax" = "100",
        "vehicleAgeMin" = "0"

    );                      
    // json encode data
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
```

How Ever I'm getting error with "unexpect" `=`   between residualValueMax and 100.
Can someone please advise me how to create JSON like that ?
Thanks

Comment: Why you are using = in array

Comment: Replacing `=` by `=>` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the `=` with `=>` in the array declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Use **=>** and not **=** for an array.